# Using Mitmproxy proxy to display flows containing defined string

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm searching for a way to filter out flows to only those, which contain defined string (or one of set of strings).
For an example...
I have set of strings teststring1, teststring2, teststring3 and I would like to see only requests/responses containing one of those strings.
Any idea how to do it in Mitmproxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a flow filter (for example by pressing `f`) and then specify a filter pattern:

- https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-filters/

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of using those flow filters? I was trying to find something but couldn't find much.

Comment: @MarcinBobowski In your case, open mitmproxy, press `f`, type `teststring1 | teststring2 | teststring3` and enter. It will filter out requests containing one of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
("teststring1" & "teststring2" & "teststring3")
```